which platform to choose for whatsapp messages processing programatically?
I need to write an app which will read whatsapp messages directed from 5 companies, to an account owned by my customer and sometimes answer these messages (send reply)
There are up to 300 messages daily, sent to my customer from these companies, about 10% should be answered.
Simple question is: which platform to choose.
Is it possible to read WhatsApp messages directed to my customer phone number using some WhatsApp Bussiess Account ?
Best Regards
Marek
